# Pass id between multiple queries in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying customer forms id row by row and that works fine. But I would also like to display the score of each form in the same row. How can i get the form_id from query 1 to work in query 2? I need the form_id to be able to sum the score for query 2.

I have added $WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE? in the code where I'm lost, what would be the correct way to solve this?

```
// get user_if from url
$user_id = $_GET['userid'];

// fetch form_id for form list
$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT form_id FROM answers where user_id=$user_id";
$result1 = @mysqli_query($con, $query1);
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

// get score based on form_id from query 1?
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(answer_value) AS Poang FROM answers q JOIN questions a ON   q.question_id = a.question_id WHERE form_id = $WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE? AND question_sort = 1");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='currentform?formid=" . $row1['form_id'] . "</a></td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['Poang'] ."</td></tr></table>"; 
}}
```

Comment: replace `$WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE` by `$row1['form_id']`

Comment: Use $row1['form_id'] instead of your WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE

Comment: hmm, i had to replace it with: ".$row['form_id']." to be able to get the sql query work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `row1['form_id']` instead of `$WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE`.

In your

```
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
```

The current result of your Select will be saved into `$row1` as array, so you can access these values like a normal array.

If you give the select an alias the key of the array will have the name of the alias, else it will have the column name from the database.

You also need to concate the strings like this

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(answer_value) AS Poang FROM answers q JOIN questions a ON   q.question_id = a.question_id WHERE form_id = ".$row1['form_id']." AND question_sort = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$WHAT-TO-PUT-HERE` by `$row1['form_id']`

like

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(answer_value) AS Poang FROM answers q 
                  JOIN questions a ON   
                  q.question_id = a.question_id 
                  WHERE form_id = '".$row1['form_id']."' AND question_sort = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with just one query:

```
SELECT
    a.form_id,
    SUM(answer_value) AS Poang
FROM
    answers a
JOIN
    questions q
WHERE
    a.user_id = $user_id
    AND
    q.question_sort = 1
GROUP BY
    a.form_id
```

Comment: At last. Some common sense.

Answer (score -1):

Your $row1 variable contains an associative array including your database row.
There for use `$row1['form_id']` or `$row1[0]` (column 0) to access the value